# Converting existing static site to Rails--how to "Take Over" existing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mod-rewrite

This may be partially a Rails question, partly an Apache question, and
partly a general web site design question.

I'm trying to convert an existing static site, hosted on a shared
Apache server, to Rails. I'd like to convert the pages over one at a
time because this is a one-man project that I'm doing for a friend,
and I only have patches of time here and there to help. Some pages
will be dynamic, and some will remain (mostly) static, but even on
those, I'd like to be able to use Rails partials so I can more easily
retain a consistent appearance. I know how to create all of the pages
I need (more or less), but I don't know what to do with them once
they're created.

For example, one page on the site has a URL like
`example.org/letters.html`. This is a long, static page, with a bunch
of letters just entered as html. Creating a controller, model, and
view for Letters should be easy enough. I'm not quite sure what the
root entry in `config/routes.rb` would look like.

I also don't know how to tell the server to use a new page, given the old
URL, *unless* I just use a redirect with, e.g., `mod_rewrite`. I don't
know how Rails would be able to "take over" an existing page
otherwise. (This might be where I need to contact the hosting company,
since I don't have direct access to the server.)

I'm guessing that, since I'm converting pages over one-by-one, I would
need to do a redirect for each page individually. But once I was done
with the site, would I be able to do just create one rule that
permanently redirects anything over? Is that even the best way to do
that?

In short, my questions more generally become:

1. What is the root entry I'd need to put in `config/routes.rb` for an existing page at `example.org`?
2. Do I need to redirect an existing page to a Rails-generated one? If
   so, how?
3. If not, what *do* I need to do?
4. How would I do this piecemeal, so I can work on one page at a time?
5. Is this even the right way to think about this project?

I took a look
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250856/adding-functionality-to-a-static-website-using-ruby-on-rails), but the answer was looking at it from the wrong angle for my needs. (I wouldn't be surprised if there's an answer here already, but I don't know what the right terms to search for would be.)

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could set up the Rails app as the primary app, and move the existing static site into its `/public` folder. By default, Rails will serve anything in `/public` at its root URL before routing any requests to the Rails stack, so you could simply remove pages from the `public` folder as you Rails-ify them. This does require a full inversion of the existing Apache site to your Rails app, though.

Comment: @RobertNubel: Thanks. That last part, "[T]his does require a full inversion of the existing Apache site to your Rails app", is what worries me. Is it simply a question of writing a few redirect rules, or is there a more involved process? Or a simpler one, for that matter?

Comment: There are a bunch of options. Normally, I'd recommend hosting your Rails app on a totally new server, setting it up, and then switching the DNS records, but that might not be an option for your situation. So, I would suggest you start by getting your Rails app up and running on the server, but serve it from a non-root location (e..g `example.org/new`). Once that's working, copy all the static website files into the app's `public/` folder, and make sure `example.org/new` functions the same as the old site currently does. Then serve the Rails app at the root of your domain.